# Which of the various Escape tags should escape from being burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There appears to be several versions of Escape/Escaped that reference escaping special characters or text strings. Should some of them be burninated?

I have only included the tags which specifically mention escaping strings. Some are software-specific, so we might not want to get rid of them all, but there is some duplication as well as some tags with few questions.

[mysql-real-escape-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-real-escape-string) - 380 questions

[html-escape-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-escape-characters) - 359 questions

[unicode-escapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unicode-escapes) - 281 questions

[html-escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-escape) - 48 questions

[escapestring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/escapestring) - 27 questions

[mysql-escape-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-escape-string) - 25 questions

[unescapestring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unescapestring) - 16 questions

[string-escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-escape) - 2 questions

The following all link to the [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/escaping) tag, so should these still appear as tag *synonyms* in their own right or not at all?

Some of these synonyms are similar to tags that are now active:

[escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/escape),[escape-character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/escape-character),[escapeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/escapeed),[escaped-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/escaped-characters),[escape-sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/escape-sequence),[unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unescape),[double-escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-escaping),[string-escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-escaping)

Comment: I rarely find any escape thing useful to be tagged. Usually it's just a single question telling you what characters are special and should be escaped. The rest is just a variation of the same question.

Comment: Escaping in itself is a very ambiguous term

Comment: I feel like escape sequences are minor enough details in terms of classification that you can just use the name of the thing you're trying to escape in (e.g. `mysql`, `html`, etc.). Otherwise, it's way too broad, different languages have different approaches to escapes and parsing (which is really what "unescaping" is, right?).

Comment: I would say the [tag:mysql-escape-string] tag should be deleted and all those questions retagged [tag:mysql-real-escape-string]

Comment: I've reached kind of a point where I only vote for burnination of a tag when it's actually harmful because the backlog is absurd.

Comment: @Joshua how about we tackle the backlog?

Comment: If you have just escaped prison, it better not be a 'catch-all' tag

Comment: Which of the various tags should [escape] burnination?

Comment: Also [tag:ansi-escape] (and related tags [tag:ansi-colors], [tag:terminal-color] (theoretically might be Windows, but seems rare at a glance), [tag:ansi] (ick, this should be fixed), [tag:vt100] (for the ones that aren't about colors, should usually be [tag:terminal-emulator] I think))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are my thoughts on this:

[mysql-real-escape-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-real-escape-string) - I don't know yet what to do about this one. It needs some retagging and editing. Otherwise, it is a valid tag for a PHP function.

[html-escape-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-escape-characters) - It's a relevant tag on its own. I can imagine someone asking a question specifically about HTML escape characters.

[unicode-escapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unicode-escapes) - Same as above, although it might be possible to synonymize with [urlencode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlencode)

[html-escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-escape) - Not entirely sure if we need a separate tag for the action of escaping to HTML and HTML escape characters, so maybe these two should be merged.

[escapestring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/escapestring) - Merged into [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/escaping)

[mysql-escape-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-escape-string) - I burninated it myself. Most of it was bad PHP questions. After removing them I was left with 3 questions and I found more suitable tags for them.

[unescapestring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unescapestring) - Good candidate for quick burnination. Probably needs a dedicated Meta post.

[string-escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-escape) - I retagged one question and now this tag has only one question, but it has a description and is relevant, so it can stay as is. It will be misused though, so I can be persuaded to retag the remaining question and remove the tag.

Comment: I don't think [[tag:unicode-escapes]] is synonymous to [[tag:urlencode]]. It rather seems to target escape sequences for unicode characters in various languages' string literals.

Comment: Given the (sadly) extensive use of `mysql_real_escape_string` I think it's reasonable to leave it as a tag for questions related to that specific function. I've updated the tag description to make it more useful.

Comment: I do find it interesting that there's no `mysqli_real_escape_string` tag...

Comment: There is a [`mysql_real_escape_string()` function in the underlying C library](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html), so that tag might make sense for non-PHP languages. At the moment, [63 questions are tagged `mysql-real-escape-string` and not `php`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-real-escape-string+-php). The tag wiki only talks about PHP, though.

Comment: "Otherwise, it is a valid tag for a PHP function." -> since when are tags for functions valid? We would have millions of tags for each language in that case. I opened up some random questions with that tag and there's no mention of said function at all even.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto What I meant to say is that it is on-topic. I am not sure how useful it is. We could probably do without this tag altogether

Comment: We don't have a tag for each and every function of a programming language, typically.

Comment: @ThomasWeller we don't, but I think it applies to lot of topics that we don't neccessarily have tags for all of them but we might have for the most important/popular ones. for example, we have tags for some classes, like [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime) or [uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableview) or [arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arraylist).

Comment: TBH, I think [mysql-real-escape-string] needs to be cleaned of any pure [PHP] questions and then merged with [mysql]. That's purely a gut instinct and could be wrong. Counterpoints welcome.